# Are there any standalone bash shells for Windows?

Tags: linux, bash

I have heard about WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) and I wanted that feature. Unfortunately, my Windows version is so low and it hasn't anniversary update, also I can't update due low space. Are there any standalone Linux bash shell, that don't require WSL and VM and have exactly same features?

Comment: You might try https://cygwin.com/

Comment: I tried it but it has not got many features!

Comment: That makes me think you didn't try very hard:  https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Comment: Does it supports theme change? I want to change it to parrot os theme.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the Windows UI, you'll need to work with a language that can interact very closely with Windows, such as [tag:powershell] or perhaps [tag:autohotkey] -- I don't know these, I'm guessing.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to skin Windows as though it were a Linux OS. Windows doesn't really support that beyond changing colors. None of the other features you're seeing in Parrot Linux will be available.

Comment: I am trying to change terminal's theme and input prompt, not Windows (I am not dumb in IT, programming and technology! Just asking software). Like transform from windows command prompt's white 'C:/system32/' input to parrot os bash's colourful input with red '┌──[%username%' + yellow '@' + cyan '%active directory%' + red '[+][' + green '-' + red '] \new_line └──>' + yellow '#'. This is confusing, so, just go and check it's bash input theme. I know it can be changed from '.bashrc', but in Cygwin it changes it to it's default or to other colours. Git bash does not supports theme changing.

Comment: Maybe the new Windows Terminal has some of the features you want? Though it would be unlikely to run on really old versions of Windows 10, you should really try to upgrade. https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701

Comment: 1. I can't update and my win version is 10.0.10586. 2. I need bash which doesn't requires wsl.